# Why $\tan{e^2}\approx 2$, and $\tan{e^3}\approx 3$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, approximation

$$\tan{e^2}=1.99362\ldots$$
$$\tan{e^3}=2.87427\ldots$$
Why are these close to $2$ and $3$?
The former seems to be especially close to $2$.

Or why are the solutions of $\tan e^x=x$ near $x\approx2$ and $x\approx3$ so close to integers?

The solutions of $\tan e^x=x$ are as follows:
$$x=1.40987943\ldots\\
x=2.00017774\ldots\\
x=2.36036677\ldots\\
x=2.62270264\ldots\\
x=2.82962192\ldots\\
x=3.00065349\ldots\\
x=3.27363173\ldots\\
x=3.38635403\ldots\\
x=3.48760393\ldots\\
x=3.57950793\ldots\\
x=3.66365002\ldots\\
x=3.74124217\ldots\\
x=3.81323250\ldots\\
x=3.88037684\ldots\\
x=3.94328751\ldots\\
x=4.00246750\ldots\\
x=4.05833510\ldots\\
\vdots$$
It seems to me that the two solutions specifically close to integers.
Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Because $e^2\approx \arctan{(2)}+2\pi$ and $e^3\approx \arctan{(3)+6\pi}$